# Alternative to a global variable for assigning struct hash keys

Tags: c, hash, struct, global-variables

How can one implement a means to supply unique ints to be used as a hash key for a hash table of structs without resorting to a global variable?

Note there may be several hash tables but each constituent struct must have a unique key across *all* hash tables as the tables can be merged together

maybe I should just use a global variable but it feels naughty

Comment: You could use a `static` variable....

Comment: yes thats moving in the right direction - still a little bit global though - wondering if there is some clever alternative - like a closure would be ideal, but its C so not quite so straightforward

Comment: or do you mean making an internal variable static as opposed to an external static variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases global variables are useful.

In this case, if you have multiple threads you may want to make it `static` (code file restricted) and access it through functions that do proper mutex locking.

Comment: If it's `static` then it's not really a global variable. It's confined to that module.

Comment: yes - that would not be an issue in this case so definitely better than a proper global - still feels a bit wrong though

Comment: thinking about it - limiting the potential impact of any static (file scope) external variable is a good argument for not lumping too many functions into the same src file

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I implemented:

```
enum CTROP {
   RESET=0,
   INCREMENT=1
};

int counter(enum CTROP ctr_op)
{
    static int n;

    switch (ctr_op) {
    case RESET:
        n=0;
        break;
    case INCREMENT:
        n++;
        break;
    default:
        print_err_log(ERR_LOG, "invalid arg for counter()", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    return n;
}
```